# Is it possible to map custom final classes in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have already made class which I wish to persist. I can't change it's code, i.e. can't put any annotations inside. Also, class is not following bean convention.

I.e. it is arbitrary complex class I wish to persist.

Is it possible to write some sort of custom serializer and deserializer (don't know how to name it) in Hibernate, so that I be able to read these classes as usual POJOs?

Comment: Is the final class implementing serializable?

Comment: @PaulWasilewski since you would like to serialize it in blob, then no :)

Comment: Then I guess the only option left is to map the class.

Comment: How? I there any custom mappers feature in Hibernate like when custom serializers/deserializers in XML and JSON libraries?

Comment: Your class do not implement serializable so using a serializer/deserializer will not work regardless which. To map means write a one serializable/persistable class which represents your none serializable class. Another option would be byte code manipulation but that's not manageable.

Comment: No true. For example in Gson, there is no need for class to implement Serializable to be serialized by custom serializer and deserializer. So, there is not reason to require it for Hibernate too.

Comment: That's true. But it works only under certain circumstances. For example if your class have a non serializable field, GSON default serialization fails.

Comment: So, the question about custom mapper / unmapper; don't know how to name it. Who distributes data from class fields to database columns and wise versa.

Comment: The JPA implementation. In your case Hibernate. But you have to follow some conventions if you are using JPA. One of them is implementing serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the first question is **can I map a "fina class"** the answer to this question is YES as long as you dont use Hibernate Enchancing or some sort of instrumentation.

Now second question. **Bean not following Bean Conventions**. I guess this means no getters and setters. You can have Attribute level access so this is again not a problem.

**Is it possible to write custom serializer in Hibernate**. The answer here is NO. Why ? Because Hibernate is not about Serialization hibernate is about SQL. There is no strict requirement that a Hibernate Entity should be serialize-able.

**Even though Hibernate does not enforce serialization. Can I still make my final class serialize-able even though it does not implement Serializable or Eternalizeable.** Yes you need to wrap it into class implementing Serializable or Externalizeable and implement the doRead doWrite methods yourself.

**Serialization to JSON or XML** - this is not part of Hibernate neither is part of JPA. Serialization to these two formats is defined as part of the Jaxb and Jax-rs specifications.

Comment: Looks like we have misunderstanding. JSON and XML were taken as an example, where we can write custom classes to read and write structured data. Similar would be good in hibernate: read and write custom class from/to database table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at hibernate `UserType` and `CompositeUserType`, with the well known [EnumUserType example](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForPersistingAnEnumWithAVARCHARColumn)

Enums are a bit like your needs : `final` class, no getters nor setters. They are not complex though, so you might need a `CompositeUserType` that allows to map several columns for one Type, rather that a `UserType`.

Then you would use it like that in your class :

```
public class MyClass { 
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "com...MyCompositeUserType")
    private ComplexFinalClassNotPojo complexObject;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this work only for fields. I would like to process entire `MyClass` from you example, without adding of annotations.

Comment: the class you do not own and cannot modify is ComplexFinalClassNotPojo in my example. Thanks to the CompositeUserType, you can map it to several database fields (all of the columns of the Table of MyClass but the `ID` column). MyClass  is code you own, and declare in your project. MyClass would contains only the table name, and the Id definition, which could be a user assigned `@Id` based on `complexObject` internal state.